# How to install Brave Browser on Elementry OS?

Tags: repositories, web-browser, internet-browser

I want to install Brave brower on Elementary OS, it is not present in the App Center or the official repos. I googled but I could not find something simple that I as a linux beginner (Noob) could understand and do. Is there a simple way to do it?something similar to sudo apt-get install Brave .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official docs of the Brave browser you can install it via  apt-get after adding the repository to your sources list:

```
curl https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brave-apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brave-apt `lsb_release -sc` main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-`lsb_release -sc`.list

sudo apt update
sudo apt install brave
```

More info: [here](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/blob/master/docs/linuxInstall.md#debian-jessie-and-ubuntu-artful-zesty-yakkety-xenial-and-trusty-amd64)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore. I keep getting a `403 Forbidden` whenever it tries to download the apt files from S3, while running `sudo apt update`

Comment: I used the work around discussed here https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/6649 To pretend like xenial after getting `403 Forbidden`, I manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-loki.list` file (loki to xenial).

Comment: You need to modify the distribution-specific information (lsb_release returned value), to use the value of Ubuntu's one instead of elementary os, i.e 'bionic' for elementary os Juno, instead of 'juno'. 
So the complete command would be:

`echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brave-apt bionic main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-bionic.list`